# How to use a saved model in Keras to predict and classify a single image?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, keras

I trained an image classifier with Keras and I ended up saving the model with the code

`model.save('model1.h5')`

Now when I'm actually trying to predict another image using this model, I'm using the code

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np

# dimensions of our images
img_width, img_height = 231, 172

# load the model we saved
model = load_model('model1.h5')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# predicting images
img = image.load_img('a.png', target_size=(img_width, img_height))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

images = np.vstack([x])
classes = model.predict_classes(images, batch_size=10)
print(classes)
```

and I get an error saying

> ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (None, 231, 172, 1) but got array with shape (1, 231, 172, 3)

The images that I use were all in GrayScale mode so I understand that I need to change the 3 to a 1 but I'm not sure how with this code?

Also, when I trained the images, I set

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
```

but I'm not exactly sure where I would put the code to rescale it, if it's even needed

Also,  I set

`batch_size = 16`

and I see in the code to predict I put

`classes = model.predict_classes(images, batch_size=10)`

Should I change that batch_size to 16 as well? Or just leave it at 10?

Thanks again guys!

Comment: First, change your image from RGB to Grayscale, you can use `opencv` or `skimage` for that and then pass it to your model

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to load an image in grayscale mode just add `grayscale=True` like this:

```
img = image.load_img('a.png', target_size=(img_width, img_height), grayscale=True)
```

Secondly, after having converted `img` to a numpy array you can rescale it by simply dividing `x` by `255.`.

Thirdly, `batch_size` parameter tells how big are batches in which computation is done. Since you make prediction for a single image it does not really matter what `batch_size` you define. Here is what Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#what-does-sample-batch-epoch-mean) says about `batch_size` for inference:

> For inference (evaluate/predict), it is recommended to pick a batch size that is as large as you can afford without going out of memory (since larger batches will usually result in faster evaluating/prediction).

Finally, there is no need to compile the model when you load it for making inference. You can safely remove `model.compile(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is here.

```
img = image.load_img('a.png', target_size=(img_width, img_height))
```

If you have target_size as (64, 64) in the trained model.

The target size during prediction should be (64, 64) and not (img_width, img_height)